# Selenium findElement never returns and causes my test to hang

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Extremely basic code and I would expect it to throw an exception if it cannot find the element(which it shouldn't because of my intentional typo). Instead, code after this line never executes and my selenium tests do not fail.

```
driver.findElement(selenium.By.css("BUTTON.button-type-primarya"))
        .click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Selenium do you use ?

Try this :

```
driver.findElement(selenium.By.css("BUTTON.button-type-primarya")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```